# Retarget .Net Framework project to .Net Core

Tags: .net

I want to retarget a .NET Framework project to be able to select .NET Core.

`BOne.Ewa.Api.csproj`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="12.0">
  <!--Project was exported from assembly: C:\Users\cobra\Downloads\Ewa\BOne.Ewa.Api.dll-->
  <Import Project="packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.props" Condition="Exists('packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.props')" />
  <Import Project="packages\Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.1.7.0\build\Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.props" Condition="Exists('packages\Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.1.7.0\build\Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.props')" />
  <Import Project="packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.props" Condition="Exists('packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.props')" />
  <Import Project="packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.props" Condition="Exists('packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.2.2.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{D65E1712-1785-4F06-922E-BA01EDC8C5BB}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AssemblyName>BOne.Ewa.Api</AssemblyName>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.0</ApplicationVersion>
    <RootNamespace>BOne.Ewa.Api</RootNamespace>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>...
```

When I change the

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

I get the following issue in Visual Studio 2019:

> An error occurred trying to load the project properties window.  Close the window and try again.
>
> Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))

Any ideas how to properly retarget solution from .NET Framework to .NET Core? Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview

Comment: @HansPassant
Ok. I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. It works. I successfully retarget this solution.

Comment: @HansPassant

I have fixed all the issues in my project. Now, it successfully compiles. Thank you very much for your help.